# How to get Kafka consumers' ip address through SDK?

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka

I have found how to get the offset and lag of a specific topic and consumer group, but how to get the ip address of consumers in the consumer group?

Java or Python SDK are both OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok...Finally I found `describe_consumer_groups` in `KafkaAdminClient`